# Event Template HELP HE

Tags: civievent, templates

An hour ago I was able to create an event template. Now I have tried to go back and create a new event template and the button to create a template has vanished and I am struggling to locate it. Please could you guide me on how to access it again?

Many thanks,

Laura
[image]

Comment: It might help if you provided the links/steps you were able to use previously, or provide an equivalent example on one of the Demo sites.

Comment: Previously I clicked on create new event. I entered in three bits of informationm event type, event name and participant role. When I did so, there was a little help icon which popped up on the right hand side which said that it is possible to create an event template. Where it said event template it directed me to a link where I could create the event template. This has now disappeared.

Comment: did you do an upgrade or anything during that 'hour'?

Answer (score 1):

It's under **Events menu >  Event Templates**.  You'll see the "Add Event Template" button there.  You can also edit existing templates from there.  See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: I have just added a photo to my question - unfortunately this is not an option. I have tried clicking on the event template but it will also come up with nothing with the indication that I can create a new template

Comment: It's much harder to help you without knowing the version of CiviCRM you're using, the CMS, and the version of your CMS.  If you update your question with those, we may be able to help more.